# How to make textbox in toolbar stretchable

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a wpf browser and I have a `Textbox` attached to a `Toolbar`. However, I find it impossible to make it strechable. The effect I'm looking for is the kind you see in Chrome. Try to resize your browser window and observe the search field and you will get what I mean.

The `Toolbar` is already extremely limited to all edits but I can't ignore the fact that it should be a soulution to this problem.

The only thing I accomplished so far is to make the `Textbox` scale based on the number of characters in it but that's not obviously what I want.

Additionally: My `Toolbar` stretches just fine.

My XAML code as follows:

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="49" Width="auto">
    <TextBox x:Name="Urlbox" Height="44" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Input URL" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" HorizontalContentAlignment="stretch"/>
</ToolBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `TextBlock` into `StackPanel` or `Grid` which will do the trick.

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="49" Width="auto">    
    <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToolBar}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
       <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ... >
    </Grid>
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried this multiple times when trying to google-solve my problem. Also, the `Stackpanel` seems to cancel the design the `Toolbar`gives to the `Textbox`.

Comment: Probably `StackPanel`'s width is not *stretched* too.

Comment: It also actually removes the buttons after the code. I guess you also messed up the code (having a `Toolbar` in a `Toolbar`), but I tried with a `Textbox` also. Didn't work.

Comment: `Toolbar` in a `Toolbar`??

Comment: @proah OK, I see) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Width="260" property from your TextBox. And add HorizontalAligment="Stretch".

Comment: Removing that makes the `Textbox` scale based on the number of characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands has a number of things that mean the TextBox won't resize.

1. You've got a fixed width
2. You've set `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` but not `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the TextBox
3. You've set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` but not `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` on the ToolBar

---

```
<ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="49" Width="auto">
    <TextBox x:Name="Urlbox" Height="44" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Input URL" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalContentAlignment="stretch" HorizontalAlignment="stretch"/>
</ToolBar>
```

Failing that, as others have said, you can try placing a Grid (not a StackPanel) inside the ToolBar and the TextBox within that Grid. A Grid will automatically take up as much space as it is given by its parent (equivalent of Width="*"), whereas a StackPanel will only take up as much space as its content requires (equivalent of Width="Auto").

Comment: Removing width causes the textbox to scale based on the number of characters in it (Causing it to be <5 in width without content). Also, the textbox won't stretch at all with your settings. I tried the Grid witdh="*" a couple of times, none worked for me. Again, I want the effect equal to the search field in chrome.

Comment: Removing width on its own causes the textbox to scale based on the characters, but specifying a fixed width means it will always be exactly that size. To be the size of its containing element it needs to have no width specified, and a `HorizontalAlignment` of Stretch. Did you do that in addition to removing the width?

Comment: And you don't need to specify the width of a Grid as * because that is their default behaviour. GridColumns are a different matter.

Comment: @proah Have you added HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AND removed the Width specifier?

Comment: Isn't it possible to set a lowest width? And yes, I copied your code and it did not stretch.